# October CMS - Extending the function of a plugin?

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I've created a plugin to extend the User plugin and I now want to extend the update function of its controller.
Actually what I'd like to do is to check some data when an admin
clicks on the Update button then, according to the data, let the admin edit the user form as usual or redirect him to the user list.
I'm trying to do this through a route in my plugin:

```
Route::get('backend/rainlab/user/users/update/{id}', '\RainLab\User\Controllers\Users@check_update');
```

in my Plugin.php file

```
 public function boot()
 {

     \RainLab\User\Controllers\Users::extend( function($controller) {
         $controller->addDynamicMethod('check_update', function($recordId = null, $context = null) use ($controller) {

              return $controller->asExtension('FormController')->update($recordId, $context);
         });

     });
  }
```

But I get a blank page. The user form is not displayed.
Can someone helps me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wont work as it will `break life-cycle of back-end` and direct `call method of controller`.

**As other solution, we can use events :) -  `backend.page.beforeDisplay`**

> **In your plugin's `plugin.php` file's boot method**

```
public function boot() {
    \Event::listen('backend.page.beforeDisplay', function($controller, $action, $params) {
        if($controller instanceof \RainLab\User\Controllers\Users) {
            // for update action
            if($action === 'update') {
                // check data ($params) and make decision based on that
                // allow user to edit or NOT
                if(true) {
                    // just redirect him to somewhere else
                    \Flash::error('Please No.');
                    return \Redirect::to('/backend/rainlab/user/users');
                }

                // if all good don't return anything and it will work as normal
            }
       }
    });
}
```

it will do the job based on condition you can allow user to edit OR not (redirect him with message to other action).

if any doubts please comment.